# How to download a picture from HTMLCanvasElement?

Tags: html, vb.net, vba, canvas

I want to download a pictures from this home page by Excel VBA.

Example.
http://www.guitarcenter.com/Gibson-Custom-Alex-Lifeson-Les-Paul-Axcess-Electric-Guitar-106521313-i1797778.gc

I can get a HTMLCamvasElement but I can't download pictures to my local folder.

Please let me know how to download those pictures.

Here is my code..

============================

Sub test_fill_form()

```
Dim url1 As String
url1 = "http://www.guitarcenter.com/Gibson-Custom-Alex-Lifeson-Les-Paul-Axcess-Electric-Guitar-106521313-i1797778.gc"

Dim oIE 'As InternetExplorer
Dim oDoc 'As HTMLDocument

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

oIE.Visible = True
oIE.navigate url1

'wait
While oIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

Set oDoc = oIE.document

'wait
While oIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

'--------------------------

Dim oDivElem 'As HTMLDivElement
Dim oCanElem 'As HTMLCanvasElement

Set oDivElem = oDoc.getElementById("s7zoomView1")
Set oCanElem = oDivElem3.getElementsByTagName("CANVAS")(1)

Stop

'I want to download a image file from oCanElem...
'Do I need to use method of 'toData' ??
```

End Sub

Comment: please provide any coding attempts

Comment: Unfortunately provided [link](http://www.guitarcenter.com/Gibson-Custom-Alex-Lifeson-Les-Paul-Axcess-Electric-Guitar-106521313-i1797778.gc) gives **product that you are searching for is sold out at this time**.

Comment: sorry, here is top url 'http://www.guitarcenter.com/Guitar.gc'

Comment: I tried to execute `oDoc.parentWindow.execScript "alert(document.getElementById('s7zoomView1').getElementsByTagName('CANVAS')(1).toDataURL('image/png'));", "javascript"` but it gives the run-time error 80020101.. It works ok with another page, maybe some issues in your site? I've posted example below.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an example of saving png image to file from canvas:

```
Sub test_toDataURL()
    ' Tools - References - Add ref to:
    ' Microsoft Internet Controls
    ' Microsoft HTML Object Library
    ' Microsoft ActveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
    ' Microsoft XML, v3.0
    Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'InternetExplorer
    Dim objDoc As MSHTML.DOMDocumentType 'As HTMLDocument
    Dim objCanvas 'As MSHTML.HTMLCanvasElement 'As HTMLCanvasElement
    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objDocElem As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim objStream As ADODB.Stream
    Dim strImg, strData, strPath
    Dim arr64decode() As Byte

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.Navigate "http://earth.nullschool.net/"
    Do While objIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set objDoc = objIE.document
    objDoc.parentWindow.execScript "alert('Testing what we have:\n\n'+document.getElementsByTagName('CANVAS')(0).toDataURL('image/png'));", "javascript"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")) ' waiting for drawing starts
    Set objCanvas = objDoc.getElementsByTagName("CANVAS")(0)
    strImg = objCanvas.toDataURL("image/png")
    If Left(strImg, 22) <> "data:image/png;base64," Then
        strImg = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAASCAIAAAACF7MiAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABpSURBVChTYzxw4AADfgBU8R83AMoyQRXiBqSquDPRmpExfTuUBwHk2GKlpQplQQCpZqio6UBZCIBpho6aCpQFASS7VFXLCsqCAzQVKvlHZ3pC2VCAqoJwiAGN+P8fzRCSXYoFEEpBDAwAPNYyBnTMkl4AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
    End If
    strData = Right(strImg, Len(strImg) - 22)
    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set objDocElem = objXML.createElement("tmp")
    objDocElem.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objDocElem.Text = strData
    arr64decode = objDocElem.NodeTypedValue
    Set objStream = New ADODB.Stream
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary ' Const adTypeBinary = 1
    objStream.Open
    objStream.Write arr64decode
    strPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\picture.png"
    objStream.SaveToFile strPath, adSaveCreateOverWrite ' Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
    objIE.Quit
    MsgBox "Saved to " & strPath
End Sub
```

I want to note that the same code works fine in VBScript, necessary just implement late binding and some other minor changes, so you may not to use MS Office at all.